# height of progress view xcode

Tags: xcode, uiprogressview, rotatetransform

Is there a way to change the height of a progress view bar in Xcode?

I am using Xcode 4.3 and need a vertical progress bar. I rotated the bar but now cannot change the height and is displays as a circle.

Also a more effective way to rotate the progress bar would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437564/how-to-increase-height-of-uiprogressview by using the iOS5 UIAppearance protocol

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some have reported that changing it's frame manually will work:

```
[self.progressView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 25)];
```

Whereas others have reported that a CGAffineTransform() works as well:

```
[self.progressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 3.0)];
```

As for rotation, use:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
[self.progressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle))];
```

Comment: anywhere you want to change its size.

Comment: anywhere in the .m file? it says 'self' is an undeclared identifier, how do I fix that?

Comment: setFrame is not working in my case. I want to adjust the height. I am using iOS7.

Answer (score 2):

This question is already answered here [How to increase height of UIProgressView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437564/how-to-increase-height-of-uiprogressview/21041670#21041670)

```
@implementation UIProgressView (customView)

-(CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width,9);
    return newSize;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Here code is help for you. you want to set uislider height change CGAffineTransformMakeScale height.

```
    UISlider *slider_progres = [[UIProgressView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 56, 320, 15)];

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 3.0f);

    slider_progres.transform = transform;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar problem to this in iOS 7.

If you use `[UIProgressView appearance]` to set the progress and track images, the progress view will appear correctly for progress bars loaded from a Xib file.

If however you programatically create a UIProgressView (after setting images through `appearance`), the appearance images will be used however it's height will be stuck and "2", the progress bar will be clipped and even calling `setFrame` won't fix it.

The fix is to programatically set the images directly on the programatically created UIProgressView - rather than relying on the appearance settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you.

```
[self.progressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 3.0)];
```

Answer (score 0):

For me that works **only** if you inherit from UIProgressView class.

```
[self.progressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 3.0)];
```

Example:

```
    @implementation CustomProgressView

        - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
        {
            self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
            if (self) {
                [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 3.0)];

            }
            return self;
        }
    @end
```

Other class:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomProgressView *cProgressView;
```