# UIProgressView custom images doesn't work in iOS 7.1

Tags: ios, uiprogressview, ios7.1

I have an app using progress views with custom images. I use the code below:

```
[cell.proStatus setTrackImage: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleGrey.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero]];
[cell.proStatus setProgressImage: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"CirclePurple.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero]];
```

It all works fine in iOS 6 and 7.0 - BUT when updating to iOS 7.1 it doesn't show the images - just the small little thin line (the standard progress view). What do I do?

I have searched and read here in stack overflow of course. And i have found the following:

[UIProgressView custom track and progress images in iOS 7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22311516/uiprogressview-custom-track-and-progress-images-in-ios-7-1)

But I can't get it to work? I'm a little new to this programming. Can someone please tell me (simple and basics) what i have to do to get it to work? In the thread I linked to the answer is to implement a JEProgressView from github. Maybe I'm just too much a beginner to completely understand how to do that. I have googled and tried, but it just won't work.

Comment: This is not hard to understand. It's a bug! Apple has broken this feature. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22314075/341994 You can't "get it to work". That is what a bug is about.

Comment: My solution is just to draw my own view that _looks_ sort of like a progress view.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the quick answer! But what about the JEProgressView workaround. How do you implement that?

Comment: I don't. I roll my own.

Comment: Okay. Thanks, I think.. But if you have an idea or guide how to do it, or your own workaround, I would like to hear it. I'm kind of stuck right now.. But thanks for your answers :-)

Comment: See the update to the linked question.  You have to set the tint color of the progress bar to clear for the progress image to work with the JEProgressView fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I have worked it out. I know it must be very basic Xcode stuff - but if there is others who have the same issue as I had, here is what I did.

- Download the JEProgressView files from github. (https://gist.github.com/JohnEstropia/9482567)
- Import them into the project.
- In the storyboard (if you use that) select the current ProgressView, and in the right side of the screen under 'Identity inspector', in the field 'Class' enter : "JEProgressView"

Maybe it is placed a little different on the screen, and you have to adjust a little afterwards in the x and y frame settings. But after these steps it should work!

Pretty simple, but for a beginner like me it took some time to figure out :-P Hopefully this can save some time for other beginners ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for iOS version 7.1 and above in customizing progress image:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] >= 7)
{
    [cell.proStatus setTrackTintColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"CircleGrey.png"]     resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero]]];
    [cell.proStatus setProgressTintColor: [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [[UIImage imageNamed:@"CirclePurple.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsZero]]];
}
```