# customize progressview / UISlider in ios

Tags: ios, uiprogressview

I would like to display the progress like the image(except the black background that is screen color). I am using progress view for this. Here user doesn't have chance to change the progress manually.

Please help me on this.

[image]

Comment: you could try what you get setting the `trackImage` and `progressImage` of the `UIProgressView`. But I guess that little circle might be a problem if the progress is low. So it could be easier to write your own progressView to do this. Or try customizing a `UISlider` which has the knob and set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO`

Comment: @robert I tried with trackimage and progressImage. but that is not reflecting. UISlider is also not working for this.

Comment: ok - seems like that doesn't work anymore since iOS7... so you can choose to do your own class, or subclass `UIProgressView` to correctly set the images and frames like mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22322367/3659846

Comment: I found the solution here http://www.raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6

Comment: added the answer in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help someone. I have implemented this behaviour with UISlider instead of UIProgressView. UISlider solves the problem.

```
UIImage *minImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_minimum.png"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *maxImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_maximum.png"]
    resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 0)];
UIImage *thumbImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"];

[self.uisliderObj setMaximumTrackImage:maxImage
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.uisliderObj setMinimumTrackImage:minImage
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.uisliderObj setThumbImage:thumbImage
    forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

source is from this [link](http://raywenderlich.com/21703/user-interface-customization-in-ios-6)

Answer (score 0):

You will find a lot of simple codes on WWW.COCOACONTROLS.COM . You can check it.

If you want to customise on own you can also subclass UIPROGRESSBAR class

and change the trackImage and progressImage of the UIProgressView.

Comment: The track and progress images can easily be set without subclassing via UIAppearance or directly from, say, a view controller.

Comment: Thats true.. There are still more properties which you can set rather than always writing every time. So I suggested to subclass to make it a general category. Depends on developer point of view how to write and what to make.

Comment: Yeah, you *can* make a subclass, but your statement that "you will have to subclass" is not accurate.