# How to show buffered data on UISlider using MpMoviePlayerController in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using `MPMoviePlayerController` to play audio and I want to show the buffered data on slider like this ...

[image]

I want to show the buffer data like red section in slider. I have tried to google it. But I didn't get any solution for it. 
and How to make slider customize?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: are you sure?....is there no way to get buffer data. @Andy

Comment: There is a way with AVPlayer but I doubt MPMoviePlayerController supports that

Comment: yeah it will be ok to me. If you will give the answer using AVPlayer @Andy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes We can Show stream data using **MPMoviePlayerController** by its **playableDuration**. I am explaining all these steps involved me to make this **custom_slider** for my **customize player**...

(You Can direct read **step 4** if you only interested in programming part)
These are the steps:

**Step 1**: **(First Design part)** i done it using standard Controls...

In Interface Builder place your UISlider immediately on top of your UIProgressView and make them the same size.

On a UISlider the background horizontal line is called the track, the trick is to make it invisible. We do this with a transparent PNG and the UISlider methods setMinimumTrackImage:forState: and setMaximumTrackImage:forState:.

In the viewDidLoad method of your view controller add:

```
[ProgressSlider setMinimumTrackImage:minImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[ProgressSlider setMaximumTrackImage:transparentImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[progressBar setTrackImage:maxImage];
[progressBar setProgressImage:streamImage];
```

where ProgressSlider refers to your UISlider and progressBar to your UIProgressView.

and you can make transparent image programmatically like this.

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions((CGSize){512,5}, NO, 0.0f);
    UIImage *transparentImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

you can change the size of it according to your progress view track image height width... I use {512,5} you can use {1,1} for default slider and progress view.

Reference taken form this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4570100/3933302

**Step 2:**

Now I tried to set the track and progress image of UIProgressView. But it was not showing the track and progress image. then i found this solution...to use this library available in github. https://gist.github.com/JohnEstropia/9482567

Now I changed occurrences of UIProgressView to JEProgressView, including those in NIBs and storyboards.

Basically, you'd need to force assigning the images directly to the UIProgressView's children UIImageViews.

The subclass is needed to override layoutSubviews, where you adjust the heights of the imageViews according to the image sizes.

Reference taken from this Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22322367/3933302

**Step 3**:

But now the question is from which will you make the image for slider and progressView. This is explained in this tutorial and You can download the psd also.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32167/photoshop-tutorial-for-developers-creating-a-custom-uislider

**Step 4:**

**Now come to programming part**..
by using the playable duration it is possible to show stream data..(which was my biggest problem)

Using **MPMovieLoadStatePlayable** we can get when The buffer has enough data that playback can begin, but it may run out of data before playback finishes.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/MPMovieLoadState

Now in your PlayAudio method...place this code..

```
-(void) playAudio:(NSURL *) url {
.............
streamTimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(loadStateChange) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
..........
}
```

and here is the definition of loadStateChange

```
-(void)loadStateChange
{
if(self.moviePlayer.loadState == MPMovieLoadStatePlayable){

    [self.moviePlayer play];

    slideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(updateProgressUI)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];
    [streamTimer invalidate];
}
else if(self.downloadList)
//if you are playing local file then it will show track with full red color
    progressBar.progress= appDel.moviePlayerController.moviePlayer.duration;
}
```

and here is the definition of updateProgressUI

```
- (void)updateProgressUI{
    if(self.moviePlayer.duration == self.moviePlayer.playableDuration){
        // all done
        [slideTimer invalidate];
    }
    progressBar.progress = self.moviePlayer.playableDuration/self.moviePlayer.duration ;

}
```

I hope this fully customize slider will help you lot in making custom player...I explained all my work in steps.....Thanks ....

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this with `MPMoviePlayerController`.

However if you switch to `AVPlayer` then you can use [`AVPlayerItem.loadedTimeRanges`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/loadedTimeRanges). It contains all information you need for visualization in your custom control.

There are number of questions that have been asked on that topic, for example:

[AVPlayer streaming progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691854/avplayer-streaming-progress)

Comment: Thanks but We can do this with MPMoviePlayerController also...using playableDuration property....

Answer (score 3):

According the documentation of `MPMoviePlayerController` (available [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMoviePlayerController/playableDuration)) you can use the `playableDuration` property to retrieve the duration that has been loaded by the player.

You would then have to subclass `UISlider` to draw the red part of your control in the `drawRect:` method.

As for `AVPlayer` you would call `loadedTimeRanges` (documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItem/loadedTimeRanges)) on the `AVPlayerItem` representing your content. That would give you an array of (as of iOS 8) a single `CMTimeRange` representing the part of your media that has been buffered. I would advise using `[NSArray firstObject]` when retrieving the time range to protect your code against a possibly empty array.