# Change Height of UIProgressView in Swift

Tags: swift, uiprogressview

I've been trying to change the size and rotation of a progress view to adopt the size of the screen. It would basically function have a filling glass effect on the screen of the phone.

I rotated it fairly harmlessly by using 
    `self.masteryProgress.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat(-90) / CGFloat(180.0) * CGFloat(M_PI)))`

I got the size of the view encasing the screen using `view.bounds` trying to get the rect and the width x height. So I'm not stuck there.

I tried using `.frame` `.drawRect` but when I use those it either breaks them or does nothing.

The height attribute seems to be locked at a constant value of 2 in interfaceBuilder.

Any solutions before I build a custom animation?

I tried setting the height of the progress bar in interfaceBuilder like some other posts said, but I need to have the progress view fill the whole screen no matter what device it's running on so that solution won't work in my case.

I ended up using 
`CGAffineTransformScale(masteryProgress.transform, view.bounds.height / 1334, (view.bounds.width / 2))`

Since I'm rotating the progressView vertically, I set the progress view to a width of 1334 (the height of the iPhone 6 Plus) and a height of 2. By dividing the height of the screen by these values it should resize to any phone perfectly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progress view height in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717895/progress-view-height-in-ios-7)

Comment: Plesae check the previous question. The autolayout way can be also applied in storyboard.

Comment: @WonjugKim That's good and all, but I need it to resize to the size of the screen and interface builder only lets you resize statically.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You can scale it by set its transform like so:

**Swift 2**

```
masteryProgress.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(masteryProgress.transform, 1, 20)
```

**Swift 3、4**

```
masteryProgress.transform = masteryProgress.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 20)
```

[image]

Comment: I was using CGAffineTransformMakeScale before. Thanks!

Comment: Hi there, I am trying to use this code for my bar, but unfortunately mine fills diagonally... any ideas?

Comment: Would be very grateful if you could take a look @Bannings http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453454/swift-uiprogressview-fills-diagonally

Comment: by doing this you lose the corner radius and make it blurry

Answer (score 55):

I faced problem while making the `UIProgressView` as round rect one. While using only the transform

```
masteryProgress.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 4)
```

I achieved **which was not my final requirement**.

[image]

while my final expectation was something like the following

[image]

I finally achieved it by following two steps

**1. Set Height Constraint from Interface Builder:**

[image]

**2. Create a custom class of `UIProgressView` and override `func layoutSubviews()` to add a custom mask layer:**

```
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let maskLayerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 4.0)
        let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer.path = maskLayerPath.cgPath
        layer.mask = maskLayer
    }
```

And here is the final result

[image]

Comment: thanks! nice implementation

Answer (score 27):

Transform still seems to be the only way to accomplish this. **Try adding it as an extension to UIProgressView** like so.

```
extension UIProgressView {

    @IBInspectable var barHeight : CGFloat {
        get {
            return transform.d * 2.0
        }
        set {
            // 2.0 Refers to the default height of 2
            let heightScale = newValue / 2.0
            let c = center
            transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, heightScale)
            center = c
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 20):

If you added UIProgressView using Interface Builder, just create height constraint and change to value what you need. That's it.

Comment: Oh wow, so right. I was fighting with transforms and disappearing round corners, but actually that was quite simple ;) Only a pity that the storyboard doesn't reflect reality.

Answer (score 7):

This will work:

```
masteryProgress.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 4)
```

Answer (score 6):

Some modification of 'Sauvik Dolui' answer:

In UIBezierPath you should set cornerRadius: like (self.frame.height / 2).
This is more universal solution than use (4.0).

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    let maskLayerPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: self.frame.height / 2)
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskLayerPath.cgPath
    layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3, it's changed to CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat, y: CGFloat). So code would be:

```
masteryProgress.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 4)
```

Comment: hi ! ... when i use CGAffineTransform for progressview and turn iphone in  landscape mode , the progressview-bar reset the scale.. why?!

Answer (score 3):

In Swift version 3.0.2 use this:

```
masteryProgress.transform = masteryProgress.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing same with [Swift - UIProgressView fills diagonally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453454/swift-uiprogressview-fills-diagonally)

After scale progressbar with

```
CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 5.0)
```

bar animation becomes filling from left top corner to right bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Putting the `UIProgressView` inside a `UIStackView` and setting the `UIStackView`'s constraints might work as well. At least worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I tried the accepted answer for Swift 5, had a label pinned to the bottom of the progressView and the label was oddly stretched. To change the height without any other issues I used it's `heightAnchor` to set it to the height I wanted.

1- create a programmatic `UIProgressView`:

```
lazy var progressView: UIProgressView = {
    let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .default)
    progressView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    progressView.trackTintColor = .white
    progressView.progressTintColor = .green
    progressView.progress = 0
    return progressView
}()
```

2- set the `heightAnchor` constraint:

```
progressView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 12).isActive = true 

progressView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
progressView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
progressView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

`progress.transform = progress.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: self.bounds.size.height)`

"**self.bounds.size.height**" is the height you want

Answer (score 0):

```
final class ProgressView: UIProgressView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        subviews.enumerated().forEach {
            $0.element.layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2
            $0.element.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }
    }
}
```

Adding height constraint and applying corner radius works fine.

UIProgressView has 2 UIImageView for track and progress. Corner radius should be applied to both subviews as given above code.

Answer (score -1):

I gave it height constraint and it worked for me. I gave it 10 Constant. But if you are creating a universal app you can also use multipliers.