# Swift - UIProgressView fills diagonally

Tags: ios, swift, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

So I set up a UIProgressView to fill after 3 seconds as well as increasing the height of the bar a bit. However when it fills up, it fills diagonally as opposed to just filling from one side to the other. The bar starts in the top right corner and then expands to fill the progress view just before it ends.

This is the code I am using:

```
import UIKit

class LoadingScreen: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
        })

        progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(progressView.transform, 1, 10)

}


}
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What is it exactly that you want to happen?

Comment: This is only a guess, but could your put your `progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(progressView.transform, 1, 10)` before the animation!

Comment: @JuanCarlosOspinaGonzalez I just want the white bit to begin on one side and act like a progress bar where it will go from 0 to 1.0 in 3 seconds

Comment: @DevAndArtist no change unfortunately...

Comment: Ok I tested it myself and I can confirm your behavior. I guess you could build some sort of progressbar yourself. You could use some autolayout constraints and modify the `.constant` for example. This would be just an UIView you will have to stretch a little. ;)

Comment: Ok I think I've solved it temporarily until I find a better way to do it. I basically just set it up with NSTimer so that every 0.001 seconds, 0.001 progress is added to the bar. Definitely not the right way to do it but it stops the diagonal scaling and looks ok...

Comment: It looks like the animation is starting from a zero rect, so you should be able to set a starting rect first: progressView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,startingHeight,0) and it will then animate from that starting shape.  It may be worth noting that progressBar.setProgress(0.5, animated: true) is the intended way to update the progress bar.

Answer (score 2):

Coming to this rather late but I just experienced this and fixed it by changing my progressView style to .Bar. Hope that helps!

```
let progressView = UIProgressView(progressViewStyle: .Bar)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the size of the progressView is incorrect.

Try to put these code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.progressView.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
    })

    progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(progressView.transform, 1, 10)
}
```

Comment: Just put that in but it didn't work. Did the same thing. I think it might be something to do with using the `.animateWithDuration` seems by default it animates diagonally. Any other ideas or workarounds? - Sorry I'm really new to all this :P