# Progressbar custom height iOS7 and iOS8 without AutoLayout

Tags: ios, ios8, progress-bar, uiprogressview

I have to implement a progressbar with custom height which changed dinamycally.
The minimum target for the project is iOS7.

I tried use this code :

```
 CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 5.0f);
 progressView.transform = transform;
```

but when user rotates the device the progressbar doesn't keep its height.

I tried to fix this problem by putting the code in viewWillLayoutSubviews method but without result.

Also, I tried this solution :
[How to increase height of UIProgressView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437564/how-to-increase-height-of-uiprogressview/21041670#21041670)

I don't use Autolayout in my project.

Any advice to fix this problem ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I suggest instead using custom progress bar like this [YLProgressBar](https://github.com/YannickL/YLProgressBar)

Comment: Thanks ! I tried to use other controls from internet but your suggestion helped me to fix my issue.