# Width and height of progressView

Tags: ios, objective-c, progress-bar, uiprogressview, uiprogressbar

How can I create `progressView` with width 100 and height 200. And rotate `progressView` on 90 degrees?

It does not work together.
Or `progressView` is turned by 90 or change size

```
self.progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0f, 3.0f);
    _progressView.transform = transform;
```

Comment: I use to rotate progresView `self.progressView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);` But max height of progresView 50

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437564/how-to-increase-height-of-uiprogressview

Comment: Why did you unaccept my answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461982/the-overall-process-in-progressview/38465976#38465976) and then delete that question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to chain your transformations.  In your sample, the 2nd assignment to `transform` effectively overwrites the first one.  This one works:

```
UIProgressView *progressBar = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
progressBar.frame = CGRectMake(50, 100, 100, 50);
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
t = CGAffineTransformScale(t, 1.0f, 50.0f);
progressBar.transform = t;
[self.view addSubview:progressBar];
```

Answer (score 0):

I read about that somewhere...I think `CGAffineTransform()` works for that

```
[self.progressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 2.0)];
```

For rotation

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((90) / 180.0 * M_PI)
[self.progressView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle))];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 2.0)
```