# Need to increase ProgressViewIOS bar height

Tags: react-native

I need to increase the Size(height) of the progress bar. Any suggestions would b helpful.

I am using ProgressViewIOS native component.

Comment: Tried using, height: 5, lineHeight: 50, minHeight: 10, borderRadius: 10.  But not achieved the desired output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27368779/4417447
Use this, if you are using native progress view control.

Answer (score 8):

The use of transform property is correct.
Its syntax should be something like

```js
<ProgressViewIOS style={styles.progressBar}/>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  progressBar: {
    width: 100,
    transform: [{ scaleX: 1.0 }, { scaleY: 2.5 }],
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve height manipulation using the transform style property.

```
transform: 'scaleX(1.0) scaleY(3.0)'
```

changing the `scaleY` number will increase or decrease the height.

Answer (score 1):

For swift 3

progressView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: 5.0)

Comment: This question is about React Native, not native development. ProgressViewIOS is a React Native component.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed my issue.
You need to style the transform and the height.

```
style={{transform: [{ scaleX: 1.0 }, { scaleY: 4}], height:12}}
```

Happy coding!

```js
{( Platform.OS === 'android' )
    ?
    ( <ProgressBarAndroid progressTintColor="#4a90e2" progress = { this.state.progress } styleAttr = "Horizontal" indeterminate = { false } /> )
    :
    ( <ProgressViewIOS style={{transform: [{ scaleX: 1.0 }, { scaleY: 4}], height:12}} progressTintColor="#4a90e2" progress = { this.state.progress } /> )
 }
```